# delete record on last match SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables linked together as follows:

```
Owner table | owner_id = Primary Key
Car table | car_id = Primary Key | owner_id = Foreign Key
```

Basically, every time a new car record is added, it is assigned to an owner. An owner can have multiple cars, but each car can only belong to one owner.

Is it possible to set a constraint or something that would delete the owner from the owner table on the last "matching" record.

For instance, owner_1 owns 5 cars. After the last car that they own is deleted, then it also drops the owner record from the database.

Comment: Sounds like you need cascade deletes. But usually these would work in the opposite direction, to delete all cars, when the owner is deleted.

Comment: @fubar cascade deleting isn't a bad idea, but if there is only 1 owner, and many cars, each time you attempt to delete a car you will get an error because other cars have the same owner. So I need something that would act like a cascade, but only on the last car

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far? It's helpful when one can see some things that might of been tried.

Comment: @mcv I have not created any statements or altered any tables yet because I am unsure if this is possible. Just thought I would poke around, maybe I am asking the question wrong. Maybe there is a function or some type of trigger that can do this that I did not learn about.

Comment: @mcv the tables and database are made, just not this specific function

Comment: Yeah but if you make a generic query or even a dummy [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a16d4e/1) it is very helpful. I mocked up a quick sample. My mind is actually drawing a blank unless you use a stored procedure. I believe MYSQL refers to them as routines.

Answer (score 2):

I think an after delete trigger would do the job. Every time you delete a car record, you should query the same car table to see if there is another car with the same owner as the one you are deleting.
something like this:

EDIT: Fixing Select Query :D

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER delete_owners_delete AFTER DELETE ON Car FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE iCounter integer;
   SELECT COUNT(owner_id) INTO @iCounter FROM car c WHERE c.owner_id = old.owner_id;
   IF (@iCounter < 1) THEN
      DELETE FROM Owner WHERE owner_id = old.owner_id;
   END IF;
END; 
$$
```

Hope it helps.
Cheers!

Comment: Interesting approach, I will try this out and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: Is the `old.owner_id` referencing the recently deleted `owner_id`? Just want to make sure I understand this correctly.

Comment: Hello mcv, Yes, you are right. Depending on what type of trigger, you have access to NEW (For updates and Inserts) and OLD (Delete & Updates) values for each field. You can take a look at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html